# Checking if an array is a diagonally dominant matrix in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, diagonal

I have an issue coding a task for my studies - an algorithm that checks if a 2d array is a Diagonally dominant matrix.

To do this i made a function:

```
      int dd_test(const int *ptr, int width, int height){

      if (width!=height)
        return -1;

      int sum=0;
      int j;

      for (int i=0;i<width;i++){
          for(j=0;j<height;j++){
            if(i!=j){
              if(*((ptr+i*width)+j)!=0)
                sum+=abs(*((ptr+i*width)+j));
              else
                continue;
            }
          }
          if(*((ptr+i*width)+j)<=sum)
            return 0;
          else if (*((ptr+i*width)+j)>sum)
            sum = 0;
      }
      return 1;
    }
```

At first it checks if it is a square matrix, and than checks if the number on diagonal is the largest in the row. If it is not, algorithm returns 0; if it is algorithm goes to the next row and do it again. 
    The main function looks like this:

```
    int main(void) {
  int wid=5, he=5;
  int matrix[5][5]={0};
  int *ma=matrix[0];

  puts("Input a 5x5 matrix: ");
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      if(scanf("%d %d %d %d %d",(ma+i*wid),((ma+i*wid)+1),((ma+i*wid)+2),((ma+i*wid)+3),((ma+i*wid)+4))!=5){
        puts("Incorrect input");
        return 1;
      }
  }

  if(dd_test(ma, wid, he)==1)
    puts("YES");
  else if (dd_test(ma, wid,he)==0)
    puts("NO");

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it always returns 0.I can't find a bug, please help me. I feel literally burnt out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ptr[i*width+j]` instead of `*((ptr+i*width)+j)`, because it's easier to read your code.

Your condition is not exact:

```
          if(*((ptr+i*width)+j)<=sum)
            return 0;
          else if (*((ptr+i*width)+j)>sum)
            sum = 0;
```

It should change to:

```
         if(ptr[i*width+i]< sum) // it's similar to if(*((ptr+i*width)+i)< sum)
            return 0;
         else 
            sum = 0;
```

You can make your code shorter by removing the `if else` condition in `for` loop:

```
int dd_test(const int *ptr, int width, int height){

    if (width!=height)
        return -1;
    int j, sum = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<width;i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for(j=0;j<height;j++)
            sum += abs(ptr[i*width+j]);
        sum -= abs(ptr[i*width+i]);

        if(ptr[i*width+i] < sum)
            return 0;
    }
     return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave your dd_test a slight modification. You accumulated the non-diagonal components of each row correctly but you ended up asking the wrong value for the diagonal component.

By the time you ask `*((ptr+i*width)+j)`, `j` will be equal to height. Instead you should use `i` since the height of the current row is also equal to the position of the diagonal component of the row.

```
int dd_test(const int* ptr, int width, int height) {
    if (width != height)
        return -1;

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                sum += abs(*((ptr + i * width) + j));
            }
        }
        if (*((ptr + i * width) + i) <= sum)
            return 0;
        else if (*((ptr + i * width) + i) > sum)
            sum = 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Hope this helps.